# Run OAuth.io Javascript SDK from a Mobile App Webview?

Tags: mobile, oauth

I'm trying to use the OAuth.io Javascript SDK from a mobile app's webview. If local js tries to connect a service like this:

```
OAuth.callback('<service>', function(err, result) {
```

...Then the connection redirect page complains:

`Missing origin or referer.`

Is there a way to send an appropriate origin or referer header from a local html/js in a webview?

Comment: I am getting the same error. Have you found a solution?